# Return next element of a list at every loop for a loading screen

Tags: python, list

I want to make a loading screen where every second, it prints `a`, `b`, or `c` one after the other (replacing the previous one), and starts again. This is what I tried but it doesn't work. It only prints `a` at every second:

```py
from time import sleep

for i in range(10):
    sleep(1)
    print(next(iter(['\ra', '\rb', '\rc'])), end=' ')
```

Comment: It only prints "a" because you're making a new iterator every time you print.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create the object outside the loop, otherwise it will get recreated on every second, and thus you always just get the first element:

```
import itertools
from time import sleep

progress = itertools.cycle(['\ra', '\rb', '\rc'])

for i in range(10):
    sleep(1)
    print(next(progress), end=' ')
```

You can (and probably should) also use [`itertools.cycle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) like I've done here, to make the options just loop back to start when the list ends.

Comment: This does it, thanks. Alternatively, is there a possibility to not use Itertools? Is there a bare bones Python way to cycle through a list over and over?

Comment: @NicolasGervais `itertools` is very much bare bones Python and you probably should just use it. But you could always check the link in my answer and re-implement `cycle` yourself using that as a guideline if you want to learn :)

Comment: I think I'll pass ;)

Answer (score 2):

You're creating the generator anew at each iteration. You could use [`itertools.cycle`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) here to keep cycling around the generator:

```
from itertools import cycle
from time import sleep

l = cycle(['\ra', '\rb', '\rc'])
for i in range(10):
    sleep(1)
    print(next(l), end=' ')
```

Comment: `for x in itertools.islice(l, 10): print(x)` etc.